# WordPress Multisite Redirection Issue

Tags: multisite

After adding new domain and creating multisite, I try to access that new domain. It shows me landing page of the primary domain.

If I log into wp-admin and then try to access the new domain, it shows me the correct page. If I'm logged out, it shows me landing page of another/primary domain.

On mobile, it seems to work correctly.

What's the deal?

Comment: Can you please share the URL?